# Abort Curses.getch if it takes too long

Tags: ruby, curses

How can I make my Ruby application do nothing and continue if `Curses.getch` takes too long (over `x` amount of milliseconds) to respond?

Example:

```
case Curses.getch
  when ?a (do stuff)
  when ?s (do stuff)
  etc.
  when takesTooLong (do nothing)
end
```

I want the application to continue if the user does not press a key in the specified amount of time.

How can I do this? I thought about doing a `sleep` after the `Curses.getch`, but the sleep would execute *after* the user presses a key.

Comment: Not sure about ruby curses, but in the C version you can call `timeout(milliseconds)` before you call `getch()` and  `getch()` will wait the specified number of milliseconds before it returns a value. If you don't press a key it returns `ERR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Curses::timeout=](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html#method-c-timeout-3D), Doorknob.